# Bootstrap table with AJAX "Loading, please wait..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to use a bootstrap table with an ajax request like in this example:
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/table-ajax.html

But, like in the example, my data don't load and I only get a message saying "Loading, please wait...".
I tried to hide the message by using `bootstrapTable('hideLoading');` but then I only get "No matching records found".

Do you have some ideas why either the example on the official website is not working ?

View some code:

```js
function ajaxRequest(params) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getAjax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      params.success({
        "rows": data,
        "total": data.length
      })
    },
    error: function(er) {
      params.error(er);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-toggle="table" data-detail-view="true" data-detail-view-icon="false" data-detail-view-by-click="true" data-ajax="ajaxRequest" data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter" data-id-field="id" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]" class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover table-responsive"
  id="rtcapi">

  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">#</th>
      <th data-field="status">Status</th>
      <th data-field="ln_demander">Last name</th>
      <th data-field="fn_demander">First name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

I tried to console.log some tests in the js function and it seems it isn't called by the html...

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: does getAjax.php return any data if opened in the browser?? also, it seems like your function isn't called anywhere, try to put it in pageload on page ready function.

Comment: Yes my getAjax.php return some json data when opened...

Comment: Ok I just found the solution thank you very much !!
The function was in $(document).ready(function() {} and wasn't called effectively... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Bootstrap and table JS?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I added all these css and js scripts :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.15.4/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>`

after `jquery.min.js`

```js
function ajaxRequest(params) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getAjax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      params.success({
        "rows": data,
        "total": data.length
      })
    },
    error: function(er) {
      params.error(er);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.15.4/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<table data-toggle="table" data-detail-view="true" data-detail-view-icon="false" data-detail-view-by-click="true" data-ajax="ajaxRequest" data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter" data-id-field="id" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]" class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover table-responsive"
  id="rtcapi">

  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">#</th>
      <th data-field="status">Status</th>
      <th data-field="ln_demander">Last name</th>
      <th data-field="fn_demander">First name</th>
      <th data-field="date_request">Date request</th>
      <th data-field="name">Name application</th>
      <th data-field="irn">IRN</th>
      <th data-field="internal">Internal/External</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="users">Users</th>
      <th data-field="country">Country</th>
      <th data-field="valid_proof">Validation</th>
      <th data-field="date_prod">Date for prod</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```